# What would change if I remove 'quiet' from grub but do not remove 'splash'?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, plymouth

I decided to remove that parameter but still use the splash screen (and maybe use a custom one). My goal was to see all of the actions and parameters that Linux and Ubuntu does when booting or shutting down, but I don't see anything. Maybe there are so little things to do and my PC is fast so I can't see them? Or is it possible than splash screen is having a problem with that and preventing for that parameters to show up over it?
Also, I have dual-boot, but I don't think that this is the problem.
I am not having performance problems, Ubuntu works fine but if I can see both things (actions and splash) I would like to see it.

Comment: I think you remove 'quiet splash' to get all the parameters to show.  Depending on your computer specs, it might go by too fast to read.  Be best to google 'remove quiet splash from grub'.  Been a few years since I did it.

Comment: if you replace quiet splash with `--verboose` then you will get all the messages, but most will be too fast to read.  If you just remove quiet splash then you will only get a few messages.

Comment: If ubuntu is working well, all you will really see is a brunch of lines with either 'okay' or 'started'.  It is only useful if there are problems with Ubuntu booting.  It is fun the first couple of times, but gets old after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splash` makes the splash screen show at startup. `quiet` hides all messages from being shown. If you remove `quiet` but not `splash` then the screen will alternate showing the splash screen and the messages. Earlier I sometimes removed both trying to see warnings and error messages but they passed by too quickly so I didn't have time to fully read the messages. It's better to use both `quiet` and `splash` and look in log files when there are errors.